# hive subquery must have a from clause?how to avoid it?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I met a problem in hive sql:

this sql is ok:

`select 20181102 as my_date`

but this don't work:

```
select * from (select 20181107 as my_date) c
```

the error is:

```
Error in semantic analysis: ERROR-0-HIVE:00003:{semantic error => sub query must have a from clause!!}}
```

I really need a sql only with `select some constants` but no `from table`
how to avoid this error?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I change the question..this is a mistake...

Comment: Which version of Hive??

Comment: Any chance that _naming_ the sub-query would fix the issue i.e. `select * from (......) x` ?

Comment: after all, why do you put a constant selection into subquery

Comment: @mangusta There is a manage system based on hive. it will change the date 
 constant everyday.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should to find the equivalent of this date and try, for example in mysql is `CURDATE`

```
select * from (select CURDATE as my_date from dual) c
```

but if you want the actual date I think you'd better do something of similar of this

```
select * from (select DATE(20181107,'YYYYMMDD') as my_date from dual) c
```

you should to see the documentation of your database

for example you can use something of similar 
`TO_DATE('07-OCT-18','dd-MON-yy')` 
or
`TO_DATE('07-OCT-18')`

Comment: for example you can use something of similar
TO_DATE('07-OCT-18','dd-MON-yy') or TO_DATE('07-OCT-18')

Comment: type of 'my_date' is int , this is not a type problem

Comment: the problem is the from into the inner query